# Testing lines in last candle crossing

Tags: testing, pine-script, levels

I would like to know if someone could help me with this part code. I have 2 arrays of lines, one for support and one for resistance. I would like to be able to detect when one line is testing a candle but just for last candle crossing.
I got this so far but this code just check previous candle.

```
for i = 0 to support.size() - 1
      
    if (high[1] > support.get(i).get_y1() and math.max(open[1],close[1])< support.get(i).get_y1()) or (low[1] < support.get(i).get_y1() and math.min(open[1],close[1])> support.get(i).get_y1()) 
          lastCrossedBar := bar_index
          deleteLine := true
          if deleteLine
               line.delete(support.get(i)) 
for i = 0 to resistance.size() - 1
    if (high[1] > resistance.get(i).get_y1() and math.max(open[1],close[1])< resistance.get(i).get_y1()) or (low[1] < resistance.get(i).get_y1() and math.min(open[1],close[1])> resistance.get(i).get_y1())
          lastCrossedBar := bar_index
          deleteLine := true
          if deleteLine        
               line.delete(resistance.get(i))
```

Thank you!

[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOf4t.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`[]` in pinescript is called [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

If you use it like `[1]` it will refer to the previous candle. So, just remove them and if you want to avoid repainting add `barstate.isconfirmed` as an additional condition to the cross.

Comment: But this way lines don´t check for last bar crossing. Did you see my image description for better understanding?